# how to input password from python script or shell script when asked during script execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sh

Hi I have below python script with below line

```
Script name :   add_cert.py

keytool -keystore client.truststore.jks -alias rby-yagpps -import -file rby-yagpps_1.crt
keytool -keystore client.truststore.jks -alias rby-yagpps -import -file rby-yagpps_1.crt
keytool -keystore client.truststore.jks -alias rby-yagpps -import -file rby-yagpps_1.crt
keytool -keystore client.truststore.jks -alias rby-yagpps -import -file rby-yagpps_1.crt
```

with each line executing by script , it asking password , i have same password for all of the above lines

how to input password automatically without manual intervention ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect). It is designed to deal with interactive programs, which seems to be your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pexpect` to automate this process. You can use [these](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) examples.

a small example of how this might look.

```
child = pexpect.spawn('./add_cert.py')
child.expect('enterpassword') # This is a regex searching for print statement of script
child.sendline('yourpassword')
# repeat your process so long as the `expect` is `enterpassword`
```

You could figure out some kind of loop that is particular to your case so that it does it efficiently.